# Correctly type an object accessed by key that stores react components that share a common generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

Given a type CommonProps

```
type CommonProps<T extends object = {}> = {
  propertyA: string;
} & T;
```

with different components using the CommonProps. For example:

```
const ComponentA = (props: CommonProps) => {
  return <div>ComponentA</div>;
};
```

also having some components that extend the common props with their own. For example:

```
type ComponentBProps = CommonProps<{
  propertyB: string;
}>;
const ComponentB = (props: ComponentBProps) => {
  return <div>ComponentB</div>;
};
```

now storing all those components into an object

```
type Keys = "keyA" | "keyB";

const Components = {
  keyA: ComponentA,
  keyB: ComponentB
};
```

### The question:

How to access/ provide typings for the Components so that the following constraints are met:

1. direct access by key results in the exact type

- a) `Components["keyA"]` expected `(props: CommonProps) => JSX.Element`
- b) `Components["keyB"]` expected `(props: ComponentBProps) => JSX.Element`

2. access by a dynamic key results in the common props type

- a) `Components[someDynamicKey]` expected `(props: CommonProps) => JSX.Element`

The given code above works for 1a and 1b but fails for 2.

### What I have tried

```
type ComponentType<T extends CommonProps = CommonProps> = (
  props: T
) => JSX.Element;

const Components: { [K in Keys]: ComponentType } = {
  keyA: ComponentA,
  keyB: ComponentB // fails because 'propertyB' is missing (obviously)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by creating a union type which contains an interface with all of the known properties and and an interface for all other *dynamic* properties as follows:

```
type ConstrainedType = {
  keyA: typeof ComponentA,
  keyB: typeof ComponentB,
}

type DynamicType = {
  [key: string]: typeof ComponentA,
}

const Components: ConstrainedType | DynamicType = {
  keyA: ComponentA,
  keyB: ComponentB,
  keyC: ComponentA
};
```

In the example above; `ConstrainedType` contains a hard rule for specific keys to have specific type values, however on the other hand `DynamicType` will cause any string key to have a value of type `typeof ComponentA`. By placing these two interfaces inside a union `KeyA` and `KeyB` will have predefined types and all other keys will need to be of `typeof ComponentA`.

To note, I used `typeof` as a quick way to define the types of the component variables and you can change them as you see fit. Additionally, the reason why the `Keys` union type from your example is not used here is because its keys have specific types, hence they had to be defined explicitly, making the union type redundant.

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWwXAdgBQE5zAZwDwAqUEAHsBCgCY5RwBGAVhAMbBQC8UA3gL4B8HbgFgAUFChgskDKACCALig5gGAJYoA5gG5RPKADIoBHSNHNUy2IjCoKwWYIAUk7DkXwkqTK4CUHAbwmoqCQVgg2KHYAQt64gh7I6FL4XKLiLtKgUYrKapom-EEi5iiWHhHRThluYRUowDHJfuwBPEUh0PClKgCG6hCUBODQnKliUADWECAKUB1wAGa1tvWyADRpk9PZc8OLy5H1URsiPKLBw1AAIiAoPQiqzEOho5sA2lMgOSrqGgC6inmS3KK3sJzOpmKFjYIMOwBqXVyfUig0uAB9rrd7o9niNhONPrNYXZ1ptPjtiUcTuJPjB3NZQbJdFogA).

Comment: Thanks for answer @Ovidijus . However, this still fails for criteria 2a. I created a codesandbox to see it in action: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-access-object-by-key-1uynv9?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: To my understanding what you want is an unknown dynamic key to default to ```ComponentA```? First of all you will need to use typeguards to get a value outside of the ```ConstrainedType``` type and then add a placeholder dynamic key called ```defaultKey``` which will default the required value to being ```ComponentA```. Please see the example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-access-object-by-key-forked-jq1mw2?file=/src/Components.tsx:917-927

Comment: The keys are finite. Given on the use case I either exactly know the key or I don't know the key but I do know that it is one of the defined keys and in that case i want to default to `(props: CommonProps) => JSX.Element`.

Comment: I made up a pretty easy solution based on your input. I just created a function that returns the component with the props/type I want. Not perfect because the caller needs to know that this function exists, but it might be acceptable. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-access-object-by-key-forked-0ujhug?file=/src/App.tsx)